# Cleaner looking XPath expression

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <span>Appointment Type 1</span>
    <span>Fri 1 January 2016</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span>Appointment Type 1</span>
    <span>Sat 2 January 2016</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span>Appointment Type 2</span>
    <span>Sat 2 January 2016</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And have figured out the following XPATH expression to select the 3rd anchor in the example:

```
//a/span[contains(text(),'Appointment Type 2')]/../span[contains(text(),'Sat 2 January 2016')]/..
```

Is there a better way to write the XPATH?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It all depends on what parts of the document you can consider *invariant* enough that you can use to set an initial context. It *may* be a position, but usually an *id*, or a certain pattern of adjacent nodes, something that occurs only once, even a string that is always there. Once you know that context, you can add additional steps and predicate to filter exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the third anchor by simply getting it by index:

```
//div/a[3]
```

Or, if you want to check for the `span` texts inside:

```
//div/a[span[1]="Appointment Type 2" and span[2]="Sat 2 January 2016"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `//a[span[contains(., 'Sat 2 January 2016')] and ../a[span[contains(., 'Appointment Type 2')]]]`. There is usually no need to use `text()`, unless you deal with mixed content and need to address single text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
//a[3]/span[2]/text()
```